# Assign Subscriber capabilities to a custom user role

Tags: user-roles

I am creating a custom user role (client) for the application I am building, and I want this role to have extremely limited capabilities.

I am using the `add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities );` to create the custom role.

```
$client_role = add_role('client', 'Client',
    array (
      'edit_posts' => false,
      'delete_posts' => false,
    ));
```

Here's my question - instead of having to list each and every available capability, and setting it to 'false', is there a way to simply assign the capabilities that are available to a 'Subscriber' to my custom user role?

Would it be better to use a filter to just change the name of 'Subscriber' to 'Client'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress subscriber have only the read capability. So you have to pass to `add_role` only the `read` parameter, like:

```
$client_role = add_role('client', 'Client',
array (
  'read' => TRUE // true allows this capability
));
```

Comment: That's correct (and what I was aiming for), but for the capabilities that I don't specify in the array - do they default to true or false?

Comment: @MarketHubb the other capabilities are false by default (for read capability). read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for roles and capabilities.